# What's the reason for deleting a particular thread twice?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I'm just curious why [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168021/trigonometric-equation-in-real-domain/1168098#1168098) was deleted *twice*. I mean, what's the motivation and how this happened? (Someone proposed it for deletion or something else happened?)

Comment: For the record, the thread is now locked in a deleted state by  Jyrki Lahtonen. In my opinion such "resolution" happens too frequently. If one insists on locking such posts then I think that it is important that this be done done in a *neutral* manner, with a balance between those left undeleted vs. deleted.  But it is not at all clear why any locking is even necessary.

Comment: Both Bill Dubuque and [Carl Mummert](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19893/11619) have criticized my peace enforcement actions today. I must be doing it right!

Comment: @Jyrki Indeed. Thanks for the link (and balance). But why not give the tug-of-wars a bit more time  to possibly resolve on their own? I hadn't seen your prior comments (including your joke).

Comment: @Hurkyl As you surely know, we don't always follow generic SE recommendations (and the link you give is not even an SE authored post but, instead, a CW answer composed by motley meta.SE users).

Comment: @Bill: It sounds like you have [ideas about another topic](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19953); why not start a meta post to discuss why threads are locked and how to do it properly? (I've deleted my previous comments)

Comment: I'd like it to be noted that in this case, six different people voted to delete -- no one voted twice.

Comment: Short answer to "why a second deletion?"  **The meta effect**

Comment: The kangaroo and her son agree to give Bugs a lift back to the United States, with a speedboat motor attached to the kangaroo's tail. The cartoon ends with Bugs telling the joey to "batten down the hatches!" When the joey replies, "I did batten them down!" Bugs replies, quoting Lou Costello, "Well, batten them down again! We'll teach those hatches!"   http://looneytunes.wikia.com/wiki/Bushy_Hare

Comment: I suspect the reason includes this post on the "reopen thread", which itself has been deleted, undeleted, and deleted again.  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19918/630

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: given that everyone can vote to delete or undelete over and over, it does seem that at some point moderator action is needed to break the cycle. It is not clear to me what method would be the best for deciding which way to go on each question.

Comment: If you really want to vote on a single question multiple times, I can let these skirmish go on an extra round or two. But if people on one side vote again, so will those on the other. Thus I don't quite see the point (unless we agree that all the users can only cast one vote). Mind you, on this occasion, the two sets of delete voters were disjoint, while the sole re-undeleter was a rerun. Something I see and also take into account as one of tie-break points.

Comment: I do wish that they would just fix the bug that allows users to vote more than once. Then everyone could vote once, and eventually things would settle down by attrition. I posted on meta.SE about this, but it got little attention, unfortunately.

Comment: Here is the link to the meta.SE pose, for those who are interested: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250433/revisiting-user-can-vote-to-delete-more-than-once

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: personally, if we are allowed to vote multiple times, I think it is better to just lock the questions, as long as the locking is done in a way that doesn't appear to be biased one direction or the other.

Comment: "I'd like it to be noted that in this case, six different people voted to delete -- no one voted twice." Maybe another meta thread (specific to how math.SE mods handle it, because it doesn't look like a network-wide consensus can be reached) can be opened to talk about this issue, @Carl? As it is I don't really understand why it even came up here (well I kinda do, if I assume some people aren't rational).

Comment: @Najib Idrissi: I feel like I have pursued both avenues. I suppose we could make a rule against voting twice, but because the system doesn't warn you if you *have* already voted to delete, it is too easy to do by accident IMO to make a hard rule against it. The current local policy seems to be that multiple votes are OK.  All the possible changes would be better with software improvements, which is why I took it to meta.SE. OTOH we could have a thread about how the moderators should respond to these delete/undelete cycles - that might give some uniformity/transparency.

Comment: @Carl Yes, that (your last sentence) is more or less what I meant; how should moderators handle such "cycles". (And yes, the fact that the system doesn't warn you is a bit annoying; personally I don't recall every post that I voted to delete...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the "how": in this case 3 users with 10k+ voted to delete the post, you can see who in a banner similar to the close banner.

Closed questions (after two days) become eligible for deletion, by votes of 10k+ users, which can be cast just like close votes; go to a question that is closed since a while to see the "delete" button.

There is also a specific section of the 10k+ tools dedicated to this, see https://math.stackexchange.com/tools "delete" that provides a way  for some coordination of such votes.

For many details on deletion see [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

For the "why": I cannot know for a fact,  but the question lacks all context and motivation, and  such questions are sometimes deleted. If you disagree with a specific deletion and want it undone a way is to post in http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio